NEXTJS and NEXTAUTH tracking user session
I'm working on a project with next.js and prisma (PostgreSQL), for authentication I use (NEXTAUTH),
I just want to know how to track a user's session (Its duration - start and end time each time he enters site)
and this is because i want to calculate the DAU (Daily active users), and other purposes, if anybody gives me ideas i'd be so thankful.
thanks in advance.

Consider a Approach, do not mark it as answer.

nextAuth provides a client side api, called getSession() or a hook called useSession().
everytime when the user enters the site, it will be authenticated, because i am assuming you have a Private route for validation.
when he enters, you will get the start time ofcourse.
when he try to close the session, means he will close the tab, or logout.
for logout, user will ofcourse click on the signout button.
for closed a tab by useer, window events will help, i have a event called beforeunload, but not recommended, here is the link, as it is not fully supported, you can do your research on it, and figure out the end time.
please do not mark this as a final answer. Thank you.

